# when i click on image then view image from firebase image path then crash app

Tags: android, image, firebase, storage, android-glide

when I click on image then view image from firebase image path then crash the app.

this code for click on image :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imagesArrayList.get(position).getImages()), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

but then get error :
[image]

Comment: What is imagesArrayList item's datatype? More description please

Comment: exception points on `Model.Image` - custom class. it just can't be used as `Uri` (whole model), but maybe you have an URL to this file, this can be shared. maybe post `Model.Image` source for further analysis

Comment: Add the stack trace as text instead so it's searchable.

Comment: I have detected the problem.so thank you, guys...